# Plot with plot markers without using ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot a continuous function with `Plot` with plot markers as if it were a `ListPlot` plot.

Simple example:
I have

```
f[x_]:=x
Plot[f[x],{x,0,10}]
```

but for external reasons I need the figure to look like that of

```
ListPlot[Table[{x,f[x]},{x,0,10}]]
```

It works well. But imagine now my `f[x]` function contains several functions:

```
f[x_]:={x,x^2,x^3}
```

Plotting with plot is the same:

```
Plot[f[x],{x,0,10}]
```

However, the conversion to a set of points with `Table` is now complicated.

The question is: what would be the easiest way (the shortest code) to produce a plot marker plot for such `f[x]`? Can it be done directly with Plot without using ListPlot and Table ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this would help:

```
f[x_]:={x,x^2,x^3};
DiscretePlot[Evaluate[f[x]], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, Filling -> None, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"a", 5}, {"b", 10}, {"c", 15}}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Odd that PlotLegend does not print the symbols defined by PlotMarkers?

Comment: @bobthechemist I could have made it do that but it is not default and just wanted to illustrate a way to 'discretize' as per q...legends always need some fiddling

Comment: Thank you. Choosing this solution as the most natural one, although two others are also good.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid using ListPlot all together, you can explore the Mesh option to Plot:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 20, MeshShading -> {None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same MeshStyle will be applied to each of the functions, making this solution somewhat limited.  If you insist on a `Plot` solution, however, we can do something silly like this:

```
Show@{Plot[#[[1]], {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 20, MeshShading -> {None}, 
     MeshStyle -> #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{f[x], {Red, Green, Blue}}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Which is which? ;)

Comment: @Kuba Yeah, limitation to this approach.

Comment: @kuba how's that :-)

Comment: Works :) but  can't compete for the shortest solution :P

Comment: @Kuba, hence the reason you'll never see me on [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

The DiscretePlot proposed by ubpdqn is a natural solution. You can, however, expand the discretization like the one you used `ListPlot[Table[{x,f[x]},{x,0,10}]]` on the list like this `f[x_]:={x,x^2,x^3}`. Indeed, this is your function:

```
f[x_] := {x, x^2, x^3};
```

Let us define a function making a list like the one you used, but a bit differently:

```
g[z_] := Table[{x, z}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}];
```

Then the solution is

```
ListPlot[g /@ f[x], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

The result should look like this: [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2:** Post-processing to replace lines with markers works in both version 9 and version 11:

```
Module[{i = 1, j}, Plot[Evaluate[funcs], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 40, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions", Joined -> False, LegendMarkers -> markers]] /. 
   Line[x_] :> (j = i++; (Inset[markers[[j]], #] & /@ x))]
```

[image]

**Update:** It turns out that, in version 9, the same trick works with `PlotStyle`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[funcs], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 PlotStyle -> (Table[With[{i = i}, 
     Function[w, Map[Function[z, Inset[i, z]], w]] @@ ## &], {i, markers}]), 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions", Joined -> False, LegendMarkers -> markers]]
```

[image]

Although much cleaner than the `MeshStyle` trick in the original answer, unfortunately, this doesn't work in version 11 whereas  `MeshStyle` trick works in both version 9 and 11.

**Original answer:**

You can use `Mesh` and inject the plot markers into the `MeshStyle` setting as follows:

```
funcs = {t Sin[t] Cos[t], t Sinc[t], Cos[t] Sinc[t] 2 t};
mesh = {20, 20, 30};
colors = ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[;; 3]];
markers = {"A", "B", "\[FilledUpTriangle]"};

Show[Module[{ins = Style[#4, #3, 16]}, Plot[#, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> #2, PlotStyle -> #3, 
     MeshStyle -> (Function[w, Map[Function[z, Inset[ins, z]], w]] @@ ## &), 
     PlotLegends -> Row[{ins, #}, Spacer[5]]]] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{funcs, mesh, colors, markers}]]
```

[image]

Change `PlotStyle -> #3` to `PlotStyle -> None` to remove the lines:
[image]