# Add marks in multiple functions in Plot

Tags: plotting

I am looking for any options to draw 2D plot of differently marked curves for given functions, thus one can distinguish it by the provided legend.

For instance:

```
Plot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t], Sin[3 t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> {"t=1", "t=2", "t=3"}]
```

[image]

The plot above is differed by colors. I seek the option to have something like
[image]

Any suggestions would be welcome.

P.S. Other ideas are admitted too, the claim is to endow the method to differ each function without the color/dashing usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In recent versions `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` may suit your needs:

```
Plot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t], Sin[3 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"t=1", "t=2", "t=3"}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

```
dat = Table[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t], Sin[3 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, 0.1}]\[Transpose];

ListLinePlot[dat,
  PlotLegends -> {"t=1", "t=2", "t=3"}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

If you wish to combine these styles with full-color plots please see my answer to:

- [Specifying non-conflicting PlotTheme options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51846/specifying-non-conflicting-plottheme-options/87282#87282)

  [image]

Comment: Are you sure about second one? My result for that is http://i.imgur.com/kTfNNBy.png

Comment: @Fibonacci Thanks for the note.  I re-checked, and my result is as shown in version 10.1 under Windows.  Which version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Actually I am working on 9.0.1, therefore may be the result is slightly different.

Comment: @Fibonacci I thought Plot Themes were officially introduced in version 10 but from your result I guess there was some implementation in 9.0.1 as well?  This method may not be applicable for you in any case.  Or maybe you can combine the result you show with xslittlegrass's recommendation of `PlotMarkers` for a result you like?

Comment: I have been updated to 10.0.1, so everything is fine. I would consider modifications for the problem, based on suggestions mentioned here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use PlotMarker in ListPlot to do that

```
data = Table[
   Table[{t, f[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π, π/10}], {f, {Sin[#] &, 
     Sin[2 #] &, Sin[3 #] &}}];

ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"t=1", "t=2", "t=3"}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Or something like

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotLegends -> {"t=1", "t=2", "t=3"}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"⋆", 20}, {"†", 20}, {"\[Square]", 
    20}}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `ListLinePlot` also

Answer (score 1):

There is an old answer of kglr which combines Plot and markers:

[Plot with plot markers without using ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44438/plot-with-plot-markers-without-using-listplot)

With some changes to work with V 13.3:

```
markers = {\[FilledSmallSquare], \[EmptyDownTriangle],  \[SixPointedStar], ""};

Module[{i = 1, j},
 Plot[{Sin[t], Sin[2 t], Sin[3 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   PlotPoints -> 48,
   MaxRecursion -> 0,
   PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.00], GrayLevel[0.01], GrayLevel[0.02], 
     GrayLevel[0.03]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend["Expressions", Joined -> False, LegendMarkers -> markers]] /. 
  Line[x_] :> (j = i++; {{Thickness[0.001], Line[x]}, (Inset[markers[[j]], #] & /@ x)})]
```

[image]